Keep reference document header when adding landscape page using officer
I have a quarto document rendering to word, and I'm using a reference document to format the document and to add a running header.
Part way through my document I add a landscape page like so:
officer::block_section(prop_section(type = "continuous"))

[landscape page content]
officer::block_section(prop_section(page_size = page_size(width = 11.693, 
                                                          height = 8.268, 
                                                          orient = "landscape"), 
                                    type = "continuous"))

But when I render the file, the running header disappears from all pages before and including the landscape page, only appearing on pages afterwards.
Other than that part to get one page landscape, I don't use officer anywhere else in the script. I'm struggling to figure out how to keep the running header on all pages - or at very least on all but the landscape page.
